# Dividing an Two number Using Loop Statement

Tags: java, division

hi i'm doing a java activity that will divide the two given numbers without using the "/" operator. I want to use a loop statement.

```
System.out.print("Enter Divident: ");
int ans1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.print("Enter Divisor: ");
int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

The output is:

```
  Enter Dividend: 25
  Enter Divisor 5
  5
```

How can solve this without using this "ans1/ans2"

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag with the homework tag.

Comment: As always Wikipedia is a great place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

Comment: @CoryKendall: [homework] tag is now OBSOLETE.

Comment: @ShashankKadne thanks, hadn't realized!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you really want to use loop to divide two numbers, you can write it like code below

```
 int c=0;
 while(ans1 >= ans2){
     ans1 -= ans2;
     c++;
 }
```

after loop `c` equals quotient and `ans1` equals reminder of division

if `abs1` and `abs2` are signed numbers, below code should be work for division

```
 boolean n1 = (ans1 & (1<<31))!=0;
 boolean n2 = (ans2 & (1<<31))!=0;
 ans1 = Math.abs(ans1);
 ans2 = Math.abs(ans2);

 int c=0;
 while(ans1 >= ans2){
     ans1 -= ans2;
     c++;
 }
 if(!n1 && n2) c = -c;
 else if(n1 && !n2){
     c = -c;
     if(ans1 > 0){
         ans1 = ans2 - ans1;
         c--;
     }
 }else if(n1 && n2){
     if(ans1 > 0){
         ans1 = ans2 - ans1;
         c++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @maba Yeah you right, loop condition should be `ans1 >= ans2`, not `ans1 > ans2`, i fixed it

Comment: @mishadoff if i write correctly, above code would be work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion:

```
//  Calculate: a / b
public int divide (int a, int b) {
    if ( a < b ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + divide ( a - b, b );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it without the */* operator and im guessing probably without shifting either the simplest loop method would be to count the number of times you need to subtract ans2 from ans1 without the remainder going below ans1.

**Pseudo code:**

```
numtimes init at 0
counter init at ans1
while counter is greater than ans2
    subtract ans2 from counter
    numtimes increase by 1

check numtimes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
System.out.print("Enter Divident: ");
int ans1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.print("Enter Divisor: ");
int ans2 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
int count=0;
while(ans1>=ans2)
{
ans1=ans1-ans2;
count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: your code looks wrong when `ans1` and `ans2` are not divisible, and while loop iterate infinitely

Answer (score 0):

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) do the trick witout `/` operator, literally.

`(new BigInteger(ans1 + "")).divide(new BigInteger(ans2 + ""))`

Answer (score -1):

Something like below ?

```
int i=1;
        int mul;
        while(true)
        {
            mul = i++;
            if(mul*(ans2)==ans1)
            {
                System.out.println(mul);
                break;
            }
            else if(mul*(ans2)>ans1)
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot be divided");
                break;
            }
        }
```