# How to divide two numbers without using the "/" symbol?

Tags: java

I wrote some code pertaining to the problem but I just can't get it to work.  After I input the two numbers, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop. Is there any way this method could work or is it outright wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arithmetic {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the numerator and denominator respectively : ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        double b = input.nextDouble();
        double c;
        for(c=0;;c+=0.000000000001){
            if(b*c==a){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to take forever, and it's not going to work in most cases, because `double`s are inexact.

Comment: What I want to know is _why_ you would ever need to do this?

Comment: Division is simply subtracting the divisor from the dividend "n" times until the remainder is <= 0. The "n" times is the quotient. If remainder is < 0, quotient is n-1.

Comment: `BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(input.next()); BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(input.next()); System.out.print(a.divide(b, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN));`

Comment: Perform a paper a d pencil division like here http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-division/

Comment: Can you use this? [Dividing an Two number Using Loop Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740750/dividing-an-two-number-using-loop-statement)

Comment: Why people vote down a legitimate learning exercise is beyond me...

Comment: @sova They are probably down voting because the OP notes: *"but I just can't get it to work"*. And does not explain what is wrong.

Comment: Ah, well at any rate, the link provided by Ascalonian a couple comments up (successive subtraction) seems like the right solution for this exercise.

Answer (score 9):

I can think of one way without a slash:

```
double c = a * Math.pow(b, -1);
```

You can also substitute a Unicode escape for the `/` character.

```
double c2 = a \u002f b;
```

You can also convert to `BigDecimal`s, use the `divide` method, and then convert the quotient back to a `double`.

```
double c3 = new BigDecimal(a).divide(new BigDecimal(b)).doubleValue();
```

Comment: while that is technically correct, it does not follow the spirit of the exercise :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use exponent and logarithm becasue exp(log(a)-log(b)) =a/b

public class HelloWorld{

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(Math.pow(10,Math.log10(a)-Math.log10(b)));
 }
```

}

You need to add checks for a>0 and b>0 and make logic so it work for all a,b but this you can do yourself.

For example if b = 0

Throw error

if a<0 and b>0

```
System.out.println(-Math.pow(10,Math.log10(-a)-Math.log10(b)));
```

etc.

Comment: I upvoted this because it's a way to use math to get around using any actual division operation.

Comment: Actually the log and exp will be calculated by Taylor/MAcLaurin series where the division is used. So there will be divisions. But this is my bet only. I need to see documentation to see how they calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println("The result is : " + (a * Math.pow(b, -1)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Num {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    double num, den, res;
    num = 10;
    den = 2;

    res = Math.pow(Math.E, (Math.log(num)-Math.log(den)));

    System.out.println(res);


    }

}
```